# Permission Error in CIFS share and Python Script

Tags: python, mount

I have a set of shares set up in my fstab, something like this

`//10.0.1.10/mydir /mnt/share cifs credentials=/root/.smblogin,uid=myuser,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=-777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

If I run my python script, I get this error

`shutil.move(filePickupPath, fileArchivePat)
<--snip-->
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/share/myfile.csv`

If I run as root (bad, I know but the permissions on this system are a mess so it was worth a shot), it works. What gives? With 0777 anyone should have write?